# Using HTML Mail Module, how to link items in the email to individual product page?

Tags: 7, media, emails, navigation

Using HTML Mail Module, I allow users to send shopping list (items) email as a notification, but when i send that email, the products in the mail are not linked to individual product page. How can I achieve that? What approach should i take?